# How to find Microsoft JScript and VBScript engines versions through powershell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, jscript

Is there any standard way to find the installed `JScript` and `VBScript` engines versions in a windows machine through `Powershell` commands or any other way around like by means of installed File version or any such way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
PS C:\> (get-item "c:\windows\system32\vbscript.dll").VersionInfo.FileVersion
5.812.10240.16384
PS C:\> (get-item "c:\windows\system32\jscript.dll").VersionInfo.FileVersion
5.812.10240.16384
```

Or, out of powershell, you can ask the engines.

```
<?XML version="1.0" standalone="yes" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<package>
<job id="checkVersions" prompt="no">
<?job error="true" debug="false" timeout="10" ?>
<script id="checkVersionVBS" language="VBScript"><![CDATA[
    Call WScript.StdOut.WriteLine ( _ 
        Join(Array( _ 
            ScriptEngine, ScriptEngineMajorVersion, ScriptEngineMinorVersion, ScriptEngineBuildVersion _ 
        ), ".") _ 
    )
]]></script>
<script id="checkVersionJS" language="JScript"><![CDATA[
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine( [
        ScriptEngine(), ScriptEngineMajorVersion(), ScriptEngineMinorVersion(), ScriptEngineBuildVersion()
    ].join('.'));
]]></script>
</job>
</package>
```

Saved as `versions.wsf` file and run as `cscript //nologo versions.wsf` you will get something like

```
W:\>cscript //nologo versions.wsf
VBScript.5.8.16384
JScript.5.8.16384
```

Comment: Nice. Trying to verify my old code. As official scripting languages, both `JScript` and `VBScript` share the same version with the host they are bundled with. Is there any possibility `(get-item "c:\windows\system32\cscipt.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion` or `cscript //logo | select-string "\d+\.\d+$" | % {$_.matches[0].value}` commands will not suffice to get both language versions?

Comment: @Kul-Tigin, at this moment I don't have an environment to test, but I remember that in XP, to optimize the behaviour in ajax environments,  Microsoft updated only the JScript engine (something relative to optimize small, frequent, memory operations). To play safe, just my opinion, you should not assume everything will match.

Answer (score 0):

***Please accept @MC NDs answer, not this.***

Wrapping @MC NDs excellent answer into a PowerShell function:

```
Function Get-MSScriptVersions {
@'
<?XML version="1.0" standalone="yes" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<package>
<job id="checkVersions" prompt="no">
<?job error="true" debug="false" timeout="10" ?>
<script id="checkVersionVBS" language="VBScript"><![CDATA[
    Call WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(Join(Array(ScriptEngine, ScriptEngineMajorVersion, ScriptEngineMinorVersion, ScriptEngineBuildVersion), "."))
]]></script>
<script id="checkVersionJS" language="JScript"><![CDATA[
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine([ScriptEngine(), ScriptEngineMajorVersion(), ScriptEngineMinorVersion(), ScriptEngineBuildVersion()].join('.'));
]]></script>
</job>
</package>
'@ | Set-Content (Join-Path $env:TEMP versions.wsf)
&cscript //nologo (Join-Path $env:TEMP versions.wsf)
Remove-Item (Join-Path $env:TEMP versions.wsf)
}

# call the function to get the versions
$scriptVersions = Get-MSScriptVersions
$scriptVersions
```

`$scriptVersions` now holds an array with two entries like this:

```
VBScript.5.8.18538
JScript.5.8.18538
```